# Export functions from dll only ordinal

Tags: delphi, dllexport

I am working on a DLL and I want that the functions I export to be exported only by ordinal not by name.

Is this possible ? If yes I would like to know how is done.

Comment: You sure can use ordinal values: http://101.lv/learn/delphi/ch19.htm. But the name isn't 'hidden', so I'm afraid you don't get the *only by* part. But of course you could name your functions `Function001`, etc.

Comment: I thought ordinal exporting was deprecated in 32 bit windows.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The only way to get Delphi to mark a function for export is to use the `exports` directive. And Delphi will always add a named entry to the PE export table for each function that you export. But it's easy enough to give the function no name.

```
library Project32;

procedure Foo;
begin
end;

exports
  Foo index 1 name '';

begin
end.
```

Comment: To the very best of my knowledge, you cannot do any better than this with the built-in tools. I guess you could post-process the PE file to remove the table of exported names and just leave the ordinals.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand You could also export all your functions with the same name: `exports Foo index 1 name 'Bite me!';` That would be the sort of thing I would do!

Comment: And the compiler doesn't object??  Even for overloaded functions? I guess not, since you specify a parameter list to differentiate them.